# Can a faculty be based on area1 and area2?

Tags: meaning, formality, letter-writing, academia

I've been writing a motivation letter for a grad school. The faculty I'm applying to is a "The Faculty of Computer Science and Mathematics". I want to emphasize that it is an interdisciplinary faculty which is the first thing I'm interested in it. There are mathematics faculties and computer science faculties separately which is the only case in my country. Should I say :

1. Your faculty is based on computer science and mathematics together which is the first reason I was need of searching more about it.
2. The fact that your faculty has a combination of computer science and mathematics has been the first thing to be interested in.
3. Your suggestion.(please)

Btw, I'm applying for a mathematics(M.S) program, I just like the opportunity to have computer science courses and research opportunities available. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, your closing paragraph seems to express most clearly what you intend.

Comment: Thank you :) But, I wrote something means almost same in the previous paragraph. I need to emphasize that some of my interest and their structure matches that interested me.

Comment: In the college I attended I got an engineering degree but took extra Computer Science courses just because I wanted to.  In my opinion just look for schools that offer both degrees.  They don’t need to be pre-packaged together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the combination of computer science and mathematics within the faculty that first attracted my interest and inspired me to research further.

Comment: What about using "search" instead of "research" in your sentence?